# identify fingerprints from oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, fingerprint

We have a program in Oracle Apex that we want to add fingerprints to identify employee.
Our fingerprint device is futronic.

Futronic company has a program that by installing it in the services.msc, a service is created. And by connecting to this service and javascript codes, I was able to display the fingerprint information on the web page and then save the fingerprint data in the oracle database as array of binary.

Now I have a problem to identify the fingerprint. Because this array is different every time.

I have been sent samples of C++, .Net, Delphi, Java, and VB codes, but we use Apex and PL/SQL, and I don't know how to use these SDKs in my program.

(I want the fingerprint device sdk written with c++ language use in pl/sql. In some places it is necessary to call functions written in C language)

Thank you for helping me

Comment: I'm not sure that I see an answerable question here.  Presumably, you'll want to take the sample code in on of the languages you've been provided and convert it to PL/SQL code.  Or set up a service using the example code and call that service from APEX.  If you have particular questions on how to convert some, say, C++ construct into PL/SQL, by al means edit your question to include the C++ code you're trying to convert, your attempt at converting it to PL/SQL, and a specific question.

Comment: No, I want the fingerprint device sdk written with c++ language use in pl/sql. In some places it is necessary to call functions written in C language